# Создание шага задания (CmdExec)

Tags: sql-server

Почему кнопка "Далее" некликабельна? Чего тут не хватает?

[image: Создание шага задания]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всего хватает. Кнопки "Далее" и "Назад" предназначены для переключения между различными шагами в рамках одного задания. Соответственно, активными они становятся в случае, если у вас создано и сохранено более одного шага в рамках одного задания. Если шаг единственный (или второй, и он еще не сохранен), то кнопки недоступны.

Answer (score 2):

Кнопка `Далее` будет активна при наличии следующего шага в задании, т.е. служит для навигации между шагами задания SQL Agent-а, аналогично работает кнопка `Назад`